# Expressing functions using the arithmetic dictionary

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models, first-order-logic

i have seen in the "logic to cs" class i take - a theorem that states: "every recursive (computable) function $f$ can be expressed using the arithmetic dictionary {$C_0, C_1, f_+(,), f_x(,), R_\le(,)$} with the structure {$D=\mathbb{N} ,C_0=0,C_1=1, f_+(a,b) =a+b, f_x(a,b)=ab, R_\le(a,b) = a\le b $}"

But we didnt prove this theorem because a part of the students didnt take the "computational models" course (i did take it though)

Where can i find a proof for this theorem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Im unsure if this question was asked already in a similar forum. If it was, i will gladly take the question down and look at the answer there :)

Comment: Can you define the elements of that "dictionary"?  I suspect that the general recursive functions is what you're basically looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_recursive_function

Comment: Do you mean "Peano Arithmetic" by arithmetic dictionary?

Comment: @Beleg yes, using the usual natural numbers structure for this dictionary

Comment: To clarify, when i said "can be expressed by the arithmetic dictionary" i meant that there exists a first order logic formula $\phi (z)$ such that $f(x) = y$ if and only if $\phi (y)$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "expressed" means here. For one definition I have in mind I think its planely false. The other definitions I have in mind all add something you're not stating here.

Comment: Yes i am sorry, i gave the wrong definition. I will now state the correct one: $\phi (x,y)$ is said to be *express* a function $f$, if $\phi$ has 2 free variables x,y and  we have for all natural numbers $a,b$ that: $f(a)=b$ iff $\phi (a,b) =True$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but you might find what you want in Theorem 3.2.1 of *Computability Theory* by S. Barry Cooper:

> All recursive functions are representable in PA.

that is for any recursive function $f$, there exists a binary predicate $F$ in the language of arithmetic such that for any natural numbers $x$ and $y$ we have
$$ f(x) = y ~\Rightarrow~ \vdash_{PA} F(x,y) $$
and
$$ f(x) \neq y ~\Rightarrow~ \vdash_{PA} \lnot F(x,y) $$
where $\vdash_{PA}$ means 'PA proves'.

This theorem is central to Gödel's famous *incompleteness theorem*, so you might also want to take a look at ch. 8 of the mentioned book where it is discussed, and this notion of 'representability' is extended to 'semi-representability', to include the c.e. sets as well.

Comment: you are right that this is not exactly what i need (and in fact, we have not even started defining provability under PA for first order logic)
although, this seems to be very similar to my question so i will take a look at that. Thanks!